Total submission information included in 510k data set
If I wanted to determine the percentage of submissions that result in a clearance (or conversely what percentage of submissions either receive NSE or are withdrawn) I would need to know the total number of submissions - in the same manner as the total number of cleared submissions. This information is not included in the 510(k) data set. Is it available somewhere else?
